# Webpack - concatenate files then use babel-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpacker

I have few js files that I want to concatenate them into a single file and then use the babel-loader on that file so the ES5+ to be transpiled into JS.

I used MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin to merge the files, but the babel loader runs first because of the build order.

Is there anyway to run the plugin first and then run the build on the file produced by the plugin?
Or do you have other idea how to achieve that?

Here is my code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin = require('webpack-merge-and-include-globally');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './webpack-test/test.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'scripts.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'webpack-test')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
            files: {
                'test.js': [path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/*.js')],
            }
        }),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Are you anticipating that merging before compiling with Babel produce a different output than the current approach? What kind of difference?

Comment: @sdgluck Yes I want the merging of the files to happen first, then the compiling with Babel

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with 'webpack-concat-files-plugin'.

```
const WebpackConcatPlugin = require('webpack-concat-files-plugin');
const babel = require("@babel/core")

plugins: [
    new WebpackConcatPlugin({
      bundles: [
        {
          src: ['*.js'],
          dest: './dist/polyfills.min.js',
          transforms: {
            after: async (code) => {
              const minifiedCode = await babel.transform(code, {
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "minify"],
              });
              return minifiedCode.code;
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running the webpack twice. By merging and then executing babel, the overall code size is reduced.